# how far can CSS "see"

Tags: css, list

I am trying to code pure CSS two step hierarchy drop down menu. I don't want to copy others code and plowing thru the field of pain by myself.

I wanted to structure it so everything would be controlled by including unordered list inside a div with an id and style everything under that id.

I am trying to nail down the logic of how css sees html structure

so my question is for example can css differentiate between

`#nav ul ul {}`

and

```
#nav ul ul ul {}
```

is this a bad approach?

I seem to be getting same effects if I blend like

```
#nav li ul {}
```

and

```
#nav li li ul{}
```

what is the right syntax if there is one concerning lists.
 every code Ive seen seems to be different and can't find definite consistency.

Thank you in advance if you can shed some light on this one.

example:

I went to code with the same logic but I can't seem to make CSS differentiate between these.

```
    #nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
    z-index:100;

}
```

and

```
   #nav ul ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}

#nav ul ul li:hover ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
z-index:200;
}
```

it ignores deeper tree and applies firs set of effect to both, namely it wont hide the second ul. (unless i specifically tell it by >

Answer (score 4):

```
#nav ul ul {}
```

and

```
#nav ul ul ul {}
```

are completely different selectors.  The first will only select a ul in #nav if it has a ul parent (in the sense of an "ancestor" and not necessarily a direct parent), while the second will only select a ul in #nav that has two ul parents.  Same with the other set.

Comment: Since the "parent" term usually refers to the immediate parent, I would encourage you to use "ancestor" instead.

Comment: I see.  I believe the term is correct as is, but it is a bit jargonish.   I'll change it to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no nesting limit for CSS selectors. However, it can save download time by giving your markup some identifiers like IDs and classes, rather than trying to write global rules for specific elements.

The reason your results are the same for

```
#nav li ul {}
```

and

```
#nav li li ul {}
```

is that you are using spaces between selectors. When CSS sees spaces between selectors, it thinks, "Look for EVERY ul that is a subordinate of a li in #nav", meaning that even elements nested very far down ( like `#nav li li li li li li ul` ) will be found. If you want to select JUST the top level ul, you can use the > sign instead, like so:

```
#nav > li > ul {}
```

The above will select elements like so (the starred element is selected):

```
<div id="nav">
  <li>
    **<ul>**
        <li>
          <ul>
```

Whereas what you're doing is this:

```
#nav li ul {}
```

Which will select this:

```
<div id="nav">
  <li>
    **<ul>**
        <li>
          **<ul>**
```

Is that more clear?

Comment: I made some addition example where I show what I can't make cSS differentiate. logic is there but it blanket applies first set of instructions to deeper tree. child.

Comment: I think you answered my question that css can only match 2 conditionals and I have to target them with > specifically if I need further down the tree. 
(if thats what you meant) and now I am looking back and thinking may be that's why Ive seen some code before that shortens the hierarchy by puting ul#nav ul {} structure .

Answer (score 1):

CSS very much can distinguish between `#nav ul ul {}` and `#nav ul ul ul {}`, they actually target different elements. One any `ul` within a `ul` within the `#nav` element, and the other any `ul` within a `ul` within a `ul` within the `#nav` element!

The reason selectors like `#nav li ul {}` and `#nav ul ul {}` product the same results is simply because of the way the HTML is structured...a `ul` found inside of a `li` would implicitly also be found in that `li`'s parent `ul` (hope that makes sense).

Some consider it good practice to keep selectors as short as possible for performance reasons (for example the suggestions you'll get for 'inefficient' selectors using YSlow or Google Page Speed to analyse your pages).

However I did just see an [interesting post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4274514.htm) on a webmaster forum which seems to disagree with that slightly.